# Sujeira na string XML, quebra de linha(\n) enviada sempre que o campo é vazio!

Tags: c#

Estou montando uma string que tem como resultado final um XML, modelo logo abaixo, e ao receber na outra ponta, um caracter de quebra de linha aparece nos campos vazios, já tentei usar replace(), regex... alguém tem uma sugestão?

```
StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

Sb.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>");
Sb.Append("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:v1=\"http://dominio.com.br/vv/operacao_lojas/optout/atualizar/SOAP/v1\">";
Sb.Append("<soapenv:Header/>");
Sb.Append("<soapenv:Body>");
Sb.Append("<v1:atualizarOptOut>");
Sb.Append("<codigoClienteCpf>{0}</codigoClienteCpf>");
Sb.Append("<codigoProduto>{1}</codigoProduto>");
Sb.Append("<statusEnvioEmail>{2}</statusEnvioEmail>");
Sb.Append("<statusEnvioSms>{3}</statusEnvioSms>");
Sb.Append("<descricaoEmailCliente>{4}</descricaoEmailCliente>");
Sb.Append("<numeroDddCelCliente>{5}</numeroDddCelCliente>");
Sb.Append("<numeroCelularCliente>{6}</numeroCelularCliente>");
Sb.Append("</v1:atualizarOptOut>");
Sb.Append("</soapenv:Body>");
Sb.Append("</soapenv:Envelope>");

var retorno = String.Format(Sb.ToString(),
obj.codigoClienteCpf,
obj.codigoProduto,
**CleanInput(obj.statusEnvioEmail.Trim()),
CleanInput(obj.statusEnvioSms.Trim()),
CleanInput(obj.descricaoEmailCliente.Trim())
CleanInput(obj.numeroDddCelCliente.Trim()),
CleanInput(obj.numeroCelularCliente.Trim())**).Replace("\n","");


private static string CleanInput(string strIn)
{
//Remove todos os caracteres não alphanuméricos exceto (.) pontos, (@) arrobas e (-) hífens
try
{
 return Regex.Replace(strIn, @"[^\w\.@-]", "",
                 RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
}
catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
{

return String.Empty;
 }
}
```

Comment: Já experimentou dessa forma `CleanInput(obj.numeroCelularCliente.Trim())).Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);`

Comment: Olá João, muito obrigado pela atenção.
Acabei de testar sua sugestão, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Como é que sabe que é um "\n" que ele está a receber?

Comment: @LucianoCastilho, Se você tem um método `CleanInput()`, você deveria aprimorá-lo para já realizar esse tratamento, assim como verificar a razão por estar recebendo esses valores incorretos em seus inputs.

Comment: @JoãoMartins , sei por que tenho acesso ao lado do mainframe, e lá ele recebe o soap com essa informação de \n.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, na verdade tem razão, mas é necessário que eu retorne um valor ou mesmo o campo vazio no de statusEnvio e é isso que faço. Pensei que poderia ser algo relacionado ao encoding, mas como no xml já informo utf-8, e no header do webrequest adiciono o content-type também para utf-8... fiquei sem saber o que fazer.

Comment: @LucianoCastilho pode colocar um exemplo do resultado? o '\n' aparece em todas as linhas em todos espaços vazios ou somente no final do xml?
Como que a outra ponta recebe esse xml? Qual o código?

Comment: @GuilhermeBatista, cara o "\n" chega no destino final nos campos que vão vazios. A outra ponta é um MainFrame, o Cics controla a recepção e retorno das informações.

Comment: @LucianoCastilho Quando você diz "campos vazios" se refere por exemplo ao campo `<codigoClienteCpf>{0}</codigoClienteCpf>`? Caso não exista valor para o {0} ele coloca o \n ? é isso?

Comment: @GuilhermeBatista, então caso não exista valor para ser colocado ele substitui por vazio mesmo. valor = "". mas quando chega no servidor.... tá lá o \n.

Comment: @LucianoCastilho agora entendi o problema. Será que este não é um erro de codificação de caracteres? Pode ser que a codificação de seu programa esteja diferente do destinatário.

Comment: @GuilhermeBatista você esta dizendo algo como encoding?
Estou enviando o encoding no WebRequest
Req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";

Comment: @LucianoCastilho isso mesmo. Seu código me parece estar correto. tente modificar o encoding e veja se funciona.

Comment: @GuilhermeBatista, então já tentei com ISO-8859-1, e nada!

Comment: @LucianoCastilho complicado essa situação. Bom, a única opção que vejo por agora é tentar remover a quebra de linha individualmente para cada campo e ver se funciona.

Comment: @GuilhermeBatista, então já fiz isso... .Replace("\n",""), individualmente e na string total

Comment: Bom dia Amigos!! Realmente não consegui resolver esse probleminha, então para não parar meu fluxo de trabalho fiz outras validações, mas não descobri o que pode ser o problema.
Obrigado pela atenção.